# CarouselView PositionChange event not get called in ContentView page Xamairn.Forms (Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, carousel

Currently, I have updated Xamarin.Forms version in my project to 5.0.0.2083. After that, I am facing some weird issues in CarouselView control. I have used Carousel and IndicatorView controls in one place, and the issue I am facing is IndicatorView is not working on an Android device.

It's working fine in iOS, the issue comes only from Android. To fix this problem I have tried to use the PositionChanged event of CarouselView but that also works in iOS only and not in Android. I have tried many things but none of them worked.

Here is my code:

```cs
<CarouselView x:Name="creditCardsList" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Loop="False" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            Margin="20,0" 
            IsScrollAnimated="True" 
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"
            Position="{Binding CarouselPosition}"
            HeightRequest="{StaticResource HeightWidth160}"
            PositionChanged="creditCardsList_PositionChanged"
            IndicatorView="CardIndicatorView">

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!--UI that I want to display-->                                 
                           </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
<IndicatorView x:Name="CardIndicatorView" 
               VerticalOptions="End" 
               Margin="{DynamicResource MarginPadding00_10_00_10}"
               IndicatorColor="Gray" 
               SelectedIndicatorColor="{StaticResource action_button_color}"
               IndicatorsShape="Square"
               ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}"/>
```

Does anyone know any workaround for this? I just want to change Indicators as I swipe items in CarouselView. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I test with `Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2083` on Android , `IndicatorView` and event `PositionChanged` works fine ,see the following screenshot below.

[image]
[image]

[image]

#### Update

Here is my testing code

**xaml**

```
  <StackLayout>
        <CarouselView x:Name="creditCardsList" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Loop="False" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            Margin="20,0" 
            IsScrollAnimated="True" 
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"
            HeightRequest="200"
            PositionChanged="creditCardsList_PositionChanged"
            IndicatorView="CardIndicatorView">

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
               
                        <Image Source="dog.png"/>
                  
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <IndicatorView
            x:Name="CardIndicatorView" 
               VerticalOptions="End" 
               Margin="20"
               IndicatorColor="Gray" 
               SelectedIndicatorColor="Red"
               IndicatorsShape="Square"
               ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**code behind**

```
    public class Model
    {
        public List<string> CardList { get; set; }
    }

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Model model = new Model();

            model.CardList = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
            this.BindingContext = model;
        }
        private void creditCardsList_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: If possible could you provide a us basic , reproducible project to test ? You can upload it to your github and attach the repo link here .

Comment: I have does check it, if I am binding data to ItemSource from Constructor it's working fine, but if I am doing it from OnAppearMethod its not working.

Comment: Please Check my update .